# confusion about alignment of two div in a single div

Tags: css

I have a box of buttons and also a chart,should be aligned in a single div,but they are not, and I have no idea how to make them aligned

**My buttons are in a box with following CSS:**

```
.CrewPrsntButtonsError {                             
    font-size:11px;
    width:100px;              
    height:100px;             
    color:black;             
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom, red 15%,  white 10%);            
}
```

**here is my Chart**:

```
<div id="Chart" style="float:left;width:20%;"></div>
```

**Considering these all :**

```
<div  style="margin-top:20px;width:100%" >
      <div id="containerBtns" style="display:none;float:right;">
             <button type="button" id="btnErrorStat" class="CrewPrsntButtonsError"></button>
             <button type="button" id="btnIdle" class="CrewPrsntButtonsError"></button>
             <button type="button" id="btnService" class="CrewPrsntButtonsError"></button>
             <button type="button" id="btnLinkDn" class="CrewPrsntButtonsError"></button>
             <button type="button" id="btnDataIn" class="CrewPrsntButtonsError" ></button>
             <button type="button" id="btnrepOff" class=CrewPrsntButtonsError"></button>
             <button type="button" id="btnCrew" class="CrewPrsntButtonsError"></button>                    
      </div>
      <div id="Chart" style="float:left;width:20%;"></div>           
</div>
```

> ScreenShot

[image: Alignment]

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please mention what are you trying to achieve? and what is the issue you face?

Comment: I want these two(chart and box of buttons) to be in a single div aligned,box on the right and chart on the left

Answer (score 0):

There are some syntax errors like missing `"`. Please try below example. I hope it will work for you.

```css
.CrewPrsntButtonsError {                             
  font-size:11px;
  width:100px;              
  height:100px;             
  color:black;             
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom, red 15%,  white 10%);            
}
.container{
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#containerBtns{
  width: 70%;
  float:left;
  background: red;
}
#Chart{
  width: 20%;
  float:right;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class='container' >
  <div id="containerBtns">
    <button type="button" id="btnErrorStat" class="CrewPrsntButtonsError">button</button>
    <button type="button" id="btnIdle" class="CrewPrsntButtonsError">button</button>
    <button type="button" id="btnService" class="CrewPrsntButtonsError">button</button>
    <button type="button" id="btnLinkDn" class="CrewPrsntButtonsError">button</button>
    <button type="button" id="btnDataIn" class="CrewPrsntButtonsError" >button</button>
    <button type="button" id="btnrepOff" class="CrewPrsntButtonsError">button</button>
    <button type="button" id="btnCrew" class="CrewPrsntButtonsError">button</button>         </div>
  <div id="Chart">chart here</div>          
</div>
```

Comment: I updated my question with a screen shot,if you see,its not aligned

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body{
                margin:0;
            }
            .container{
                margin-top:20px;
                width:100%
            }
            .sub-container{
                text-align: center;
                box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.16), 0 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.08);
                padding:10px;
            }
            .chartContainer{
                float:left;
                width:60%;
            }
            .buttonContainer{
                float: right;
                width:30%;
            }
            button{
                background: #DBE6F6;  /* fallback for old browsers */
                background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #C5796D, #DBE6F6);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
                background: linear-gradient(to right, #C5796D, #DBE6F6); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div class="container">
                    <div id="chartContainer" class="chartContainer sub-container">
                        Chart
                    </div>
                    <div id="buttonContainer" class="buttonContainer sub-container">
                            <button type="button" id="btnErrorStat" class="CrewPrsntButtonsError">button</button>
                            <button type="button" id="btnIdle" class="CrewPrsntButtonsError">button</button>
                            <button type="button" id="btnService" class="CrewPrsntButtonsError">button</button>
                            <button type="button" id="btnLinkDn" class="CrewPrsntButtonsError">button</button>
                            <button type="button" id="btnDataIn" class="CrewPrsntButtonsError" >button</button>
                            <button type="button" id="btnrepOff" class="CrewPrsntButtonsError">button</button>
                            <button type="button" id="btnCrew" class="CrewPrsntButtonsError">button</button>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```